# Why Javascript unshift method adds quotes?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to write a piece of Javascript that creates an array.
inside of the array, the syntax is strict because it then need to be parsed by a MapViewer.
However, I can't seem to find why everytime I push an element into my array, this element has quotes around ?

Here is my code :

```js
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var tempMarkers = [];
while (clusters.length - i > 0) {

  if (i % 3 == 0) {
    for (j = 0; j < clusters[i].length; j++) {
      tempMarkers.unshift("{latitude:" + tempLocationsArray[clusters[i][j]][1] + ",longitude:" +
        tempLocationsArray[clusters[i][j]][0] + ",tintColor: MapView.PinColors.GREEN}");
    }

  } else if (i % 3 == 1) {

    for (j = 0; j < clusters[i].length; j++) {
      tempMarkers.unshift("{latitude:" + tempLocationsArray[clusters[i][j]][1] + ",longitude:" +
        tempLocationsArray[clusters[i][j]][0] + ",tintColor: MapView.PinColors.RED}");
    }

  } else {

    for (j = 0; j < clusters[i].length; j++) {
      tempMarkers.unshift("{latitude:" + tempLocationsArray[clusters[i][j]][1] + ",longitude:" +
        tempLocationsArray[clusters[i][j]][0] + ",tintColor: MapView.PinColors.PURPLE}");
    }
  }

  i++;
}
console.log(tempMarkers);
```

And this is what I see in the console :

```js
["{latitude:37.33182081,longitude:-122.03038642,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.RED}",
  "{latitude:37.33178632,longitude:-122.0306262,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.GREEN}",
  "{latitude:37.33162007,longitude:-122.03070577,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.PURPLE}",
  "{latitude:37.33142585,longitude:-122.03072774,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.RED}",
  "{latitude:37.33124551,longitude:-122.03073664,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.GREEN}",
  "{latitude:37.33108059,longitude:-122.03068245,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.PURPLE}",
  "{latitude:37.33091383,longitude:-122.03061321,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.RED}",
  "{latitude:37.3307498,longitude:-122.03054302,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.GREEN}",
  "{latitude:37.33069778,longitude:-122.03035543,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.PURPLE}",
  "{latitude:37.33067203,longitude:-122.03018068,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.RED}",
  "{latitude:37.33067784,longitude:-122.02998825,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.GREEN}",
  "{latitude:37.33068906,longitude:-122.02976028,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.PURPLE}",
  "{latitude:37.33070167,longitude:-122.02952527,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.RED}",
  "{latitude:37.33045837,longitude:-122.02866686,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.GREEN}",
  "{latitude:37.32795258,longitude:-122.01982651,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.PURPLE}",
  "{latitude:37.32465631,longitude:-122.02308996,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.RED}",
  "{latitude:37.32632152,longitude:-122.02614004,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.GREEN}",
  "{latitude:37.33070542,longitude:-122.02915124,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.PURPLE}",
  "{latitude:37.33019844,longitude:-122.02479669,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.RED}",
  "{latitude:37.32463343,longitude:-122.0228739,tintColor: MapView.PinColors.GREEN}"
]
```

Do you see the reason why I have these quotes ?

Comment: Your array doesn't contain quotation marks, but it does contain strings - which are shown in the console with quotes, so...

Comment: Of course, thank you @nnnnnn !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing it as string with double quotes, that's why its showing it there. That's not because of unshift.

```
 tempMarkers.unshift("{latitude:" + tempLocationsArray[clusters[i][j]][1] + ",longitude:" +
```

Try below syntax of creating hash to avoid double quotes.

```
tempMarkers.unshift({"latitude": tempLocationsArray[clusters[i][j]][1] , "longitude": tempLocationsArray[clusters[i][j]][0], "tintColor": MapView.PinColors.GREEN});
```